# Databind to a property inside a object returned by a extension method attached to the binding object

Tags: c#, wpf

Not sure I got the vernacular right, so hopefully a code example will clarify.

```
public class myClassObj
{
    public string aProperty {get;}
}
public class anotherClassObj
{
    public string bProperty {get;}
}
```

Then I have a static extension method:

```
public static anotherClassObj getOtherObj(this myClassObj obj)
{
    anotherClassObj returnObj = new anotherClassObj();
    return returnObj;
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding aProperty}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding getOtherObj().bProperty}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Overlooking the obvious syntax errors and lack of constructors and such, is the idea of something like this possible?

Basically I want to extend the binding object to expose more properties than are part of the actual object being bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the idea of something like this possible?

The *idea*? Yes. The exact mechanism you're asking for? No.

WPF's XAML binding syntax requires a property path on the source object. An extension method is a *compile-time* construct. At run-time, it's just a call to a static method in a completely different class from the one being passed to the method. The binding system has no practical way to efficiently look up extension methods.

IMHO, the best alternative would be to use the ["decorator pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or similar technique to wrap your original model object in a model object that exposes the extension method as a property, and then bind to the *decorated* object. E.g.:

```
public class myClassObj
{
    public string aProperty {get;}
}

public class DecoratedClassObj : myClassObj
{
    public anotherClassObj OtherObj { get { return this.getOtherObj(); } }
}
```

then…

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding aProperty}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherObj}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Naturally, your model object would have to be instantiated as `DecoratedClassObj` instead of `myClassObj`, and that instance used as the model object (wherever your template is being used). The above shows decorating via inheritance. An alternative is to use composition instead; in that approach, you'd have to replicate in the decorator object all of the properties (and other features) you need from the decorated object.

Note that by decorating, you then also have the option of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, to allow the bound state to be updated if in fact the underlying data that affects the return value of the `getOtherObj()` method changes. It even allows property-setter access to that underlying data, should there be a need to modify it through the model object.

Other options include:

1. Write your own XAML markup extension, to handle the extension-method syntax you want to use. This will give you similar syntax in the XAML (but using your own extension rather than the `{Binding}` extension). You'll probably want in this approach to still create a general-purpose proxy object that can be configured similar to the decorator object suggested above, so that it can participate in binding to the actual target property (i.e. `Text`).
2. Write an attached property. In this case, the XAML will not look like what you have; instead of binding to the `Text` property, you'd have some attached property like `MyAttachedPropertyClass.MyAttachedProperty="MyStaticClass.getOtherObj"`, where your attached property sets the `Text` property by finding (presumably by reflection) and calling the `getOtherObj()` extension method. You could make the attached property value as complicated as you like/need to, such as making it a parseable string value containing the target property name as well as the extension method class and name, or even making it a user-defined object that stores such details. For that matter, instead of just setting the target property once, you could have a proxy object similar to that as suggested in the previous alternative.

Personally, I *much* prefer the idea of simply decorating the original model object. It's a lot easier, and IMHO is much easier to understand in its implementation. I merely offer these other options for completeness, to give you an idea of what would be needed to avoid having to write an explicit decorator. :)

Comment: Yea I think I may have been overthinking my issue, I'm going a similar route but instead of using an inherited class I am going to wrap the class in a continuing class with my extended objects then have the original class  as a "child" therein. Due to a variety of reasons simply extending the class will not work as the mapped class is already an (unknown) extension of the base and cannot easily convert back to bas or any inheritors of base due to unknown properties contained in the inherited class.... fun...

Comment: _"I am going to wrap the class"_ -- yes, that is the "composition" alternative which I mentioned in the above answer. It should work as well, albeit at the inconvenience of having to surface and then delegate features you need from the wrapped class.